# Play WAV in Raspberry Pi in C/C++, have to use dsp?

Tags: c, audio, raspberry-pi, signal-processing, wav

I'm currently trying to play WAV file using C or C++, (I want to know how the WAV file can be played in detail). However, all the sample codes I found trying to detect /dev/dsp first, (e.g. [github example](https://github.com/lichray/wavplay/blob/master/wavplay.h)). I am working on Raspberry Pi, and I cannot find where the dsp is.

My question is do I have to use dsp in order to make wav playing work? Otherwise, it there any other solution? And I never use dsp before.

(ps: I already know the format in wav file and I know how to read it, I'm just curious about playing it).

Comment: that repo you mention is obsolete ... modern linux OS no longer have that device ... there are tons of tutorials on how to play audio using x,y,z

Comment: @ScottStensland I came here to ask question just because I cannot find anything else other than dsp. Let me clarify my question, I don't want some simple command such as aplay to play the wav file, I wish to know ***how to write / where to write*** the audio signal in order to play it. I wish to get some hint from here.

Answer (score 1):

In short your question:

> Do I have to use DSP in order to make wav playing work?

**The answer is no.**

DSP (Digital Signal Processing) is the term used to describe taking an original digital signal, and looking at the waveform to then apply some sort of processing (i.e. filtering, delay, modulation... the list goes on ). If you're interested I'm sure you'll find more on DSP easily but here's a [short article](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/an-introduction-to-digital-signal-processing/) to get started.

Since all you want to do is play back a .wav file, the process is simply reading the .wav file [header information](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/) (finding out the metadata -> sample rate, number of samples...), and then playing back the .wav data with the correct parameters described in the header information.

## 1. Play back the .wav raw data

Since you said you already know how to read the .wav file, I'm assuming you just want to play an array of the audio data?

The most common encountered technique for doing this in C/C++ (on an OS) is using [portaudio](http://www.portaudio.com/). This is a cross platform (Mac, Win and Linux supported) audio IO library written in C, and can be called from either C/C++. They provide [examples in their documentation](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs-dev/group__examples__src.html) for reading/writing .wav files, as well as non-blocking & blocking playback. I think this is what you are looking for and if you get stuck there are plenty of SO posts or people that can help you out.

It also supports real-time recording and playback if that is of any use for your project (i.e. would let you do real-time DSP if you wanted to).

There are also many other bindings for [portaudio](http://www.portaudio.com/) in other languages like [PyAudio](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/) (Python), [PlayRec](http://www.playrec.co.uk/) (Matlab/Octave), [rust-portaudio](https://github.com/RustAudio/rust-portaudio) (Rust)... and many others if you needed them in a different language.

Otherwise there are lower level libraries that would give you more access, but that's sometimes not what you need, but here's a [link to the ALSA project examples](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/examples.html). [Portaudio](http://www.portaudio.com/) uses [ALSA](https://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Main_Page) if built with it on Linux.

## 2. Try some DSP!

Since you already have the audio data you can do what you want with it. If this is a learning project I would definitely suggest trying some DSP programming as it helps with all types of signal processing ([singular images](https://www.practicepython.org/blog/2016/12/20/instagram-filters-python.html), [videos](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Matlab/Matlab_Tutorial_Video_Processing_1_Object_Detection_by_Color_Thresholding.php) and much more difficult areas -> essentially its all the same theory as audio).

I would recommend trying simple DSP tasks in higher level languages (particularly in [Python](https://www.python.org/) or [Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab.html)/[Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) since these are usually the go to for audio DSP prototyping). If you want to get into audio programming I think this is a great way to start, and if you already have the C/C++ knowledge then transfering the higher level language theory to C/C++ can come easy :)